# C# Jquery Ajax Post Multiple Data Parameters

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

In my c# mvc4 application I have three objects I wish to pass to an ActionResult using an AJAX post with Jquery.  The objects are two strings and a form collection.  Ive had no problems passing only the form collection, but cant seem to get the syntax correct for passing all three.  Here is what Ive tried:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChangeName').click(function (e) {
            var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
            var origname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="myName"]').first().val();
            var newname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="updatedName"]').first().val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {tdata + origname + newname},
                url: "Home/ChangeName",
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
        });
```

Ive also tried commas after each variable name in the `data:` section with and without the brackets.  How can I pass all three?  When its been successful both string values have populated correctly when debugging but the values dont appear in the ActionResult and show null instead.
Ive also tried placing this below data:  `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",`

Here is the beginning of my ActionResult as well:

```
 public ActionResult ChangeName(string Name, string updatedName, FormCollection mCollection)
```

Comment: `{}` you are constructing an object, an object has `key: value` pairs, you are concatenating strings within the object without assigning any `key:value` pairs. `data : { tdata : tdata, origname : origname, newname : newname}`, or simply `data : "tdata="+tdata+"&origname="+origname+"&newname="+newname;`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I just tried both of your suggestions and once again when debugging the values populate in Firebug but as soon as the code hits the ActionResult both of the string values are shown as null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ChangeName').click(function (e) {
            var tdata = $('#form1').serialize();
            var origname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="myName"]').first().val();
            var newname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="updatedName"]').first().val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    mCollection: tdata,
                    Name: origname,
                    updatedName: newname
                },
                url: "Home/ChangeName",
                success: function (result) { success(result); }
            });
        });
```

Comment: However, this is breaking my intended functionality by adding origname and newname to the FormCollection.  Is there a way to send all three of these without them being included in the FormCollection object?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you are putting the origname  and newname in the ajax request.
Try this:

```
var origname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="myName"]').first().val();
var newname = $('#NameDiv').find('input[name="updatedName"]').first().val();
$.ajax({
     url: 'Home/ChangeName',
     type: "POST",
     data: $("#form1").serialize() + "&origname =" + origname + "&newname =" + newname, 
     success: function (result) { success(result); }
});
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion as well and Im getting the same results.  Both string values being null when the code reaches the ActionResult.

Comment: In that case make sure you are reading the origname  and newname  value by jQuery properly. It may be possible that the selector u r using to get these values returns to value. It works for me very well.

Comment: Im not sure that I understand you, but as I mentioned above when debugging in Firebug origname and newname both show the correct values.  Its only when I reach the ActionResult to which they are passed that the values disappear and the parameters are null.  I believe my problem may be not knowing what content type to assign or that it isnt set up correctly to pass multiple object types like a Form Collection and strings together in the same POST.