# How to get latitude and longitude of an address and save to database

Tags: c#, javascript, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a html form where the user enters his address (geo location - street, city, and so on). Now i want to retrieve the latitude and longitude of that address when the user clicks submit button. My code looks like this:
View:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm(new { onsubmit = "return getCoordinates();" }))
{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function getCoordinates() {
            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('@Html.Id("address")').value;

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {

                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat;
                    var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.long;
                    alert(latitude);
                  document.getElementById('@Html.Id("latitude")').value = latitude;
                    document.getElementById('@Html.Id("longitude")').value = longitude;
                }
            });
}
   </script>
   @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please correct the errors and try again")

    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.latitude)
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.longitude)
      <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.address)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.address)
        </div>
      }
```

Model:

```
        public class RentOutSpace
        {
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string latitude { get; set; }
        [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
        public string longitude { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        }
```

Controller

```
              [HttpPost]
              public ActionResult AddSpace(RentOutSpace rentModel)
              {
            Session.Store(rentModel);
            Session.SaveChanges();
            return View();
              }
```

My question is how can i pass the field value of the address to my JavaScript function and pass the latitude and longitude variables values to my model, so i can save them in a database?

Comment: You are almost there. Where is your textbox? You could take the value of the textbox using JavaScript (for example $("#idOfTextBox).text with jQuery or document.getElementById('idOfTextBox').value using pure JavaScript) and use the value instead of the hardcoded string, something like: `var address = document.getElementById('idOfTextBox').value;`. For the *save to database* part, you need to create a model for your data and pass them forward to an action to save them to the database.

Comment: I have updated my code.I have created hidden fields whose values are set through javascript but latitude and longitude are null when i debuged my code.

Comment: You need to put the fields also in the form, so that they are transferred to the controller. Then: since you call a JavaScript function when your form is submitted, you need to call the controller action at the end of your javascript success handler passing the filled model! Your current code has a type error - fix the document keyword in the success javascript function.

Comment: Now i have accessed the field through id.But i did not get how can i call controller action after javascript function.Can you modify the code please for my understanding.

Comment: One possibility would be to use the [jQuery post method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/). An example could be found in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15996290/c-sharp-jquery-ajax-post-multiple-data-parameters). This way you will call the controller action from the javascript function. You should place your call just after the code in your function, where you are getting the values of the lat / lon variables.

Answer (score 0):

This page seems to offer what you're after via jquery and $.post()

See section "Sending Form Data via AJAX"

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/working-with-http/sending-html-form-data,-part-1